# Google AppEngine - Firewall Notification:Your access has been blocked by firewall policy 732

Tags: google-app-engine, firewall, google-cloud-platform

I have written a WebApp, which is deployed on Google AppEngine. I am trying to fetch a url in my app.. It shows the following error:

> Firewall Notification - Your access has been blocked by firewall
>   policy 732. If you have any further concerns, please contact your
>   network administrator for more information.

This is how I am fetching the url.. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(REQUEST_TIME_OUT);
conn.setReadTimeout(REQUEST_TIME_OUT);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
int length = dataToBePost.length();
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", (String.valueOf(length)));
OutputStreamWriter wr = new  OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(dataToBePost);
wr.flush();
InputStream inStream = conn.getInputStream();
//using inStream now
```

NOTE: This is happening only when I deploy my app on Google AppEngine, and if I deploy my app on my local server, it works fine.

The url which I am trying to fetch is outside from Google Cloud/AppEngine network..

Is there any specific thing I have to do to make it work on AppEngine?

Comment: I suspect that Google has some firewalls, which blocks the request.. but not sure whether if there is any way to allow the request on App Engine..

Comment: I seriously doubt this is coming from Google. If you have a network administrator you can ask about it, start there.

Comment: It sounds like there is a firewall in front of the location referenced by `urlString` and they are blocking you for some reason. Maybe abuse.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Fortinet Firewall notification.
That mean that your administrator blocked you that website.

I don't think Google use Fortinet, they have their own technology. BTW that sound correct as you are able to connect to it when localhost, and your IT block certain connection, like this one.

Source: I have the same at work. Good luck!